# Задача по выводу информации по выручке в разрезе месяца в SQL

Tags: sql

Прошу помощи с решением данной задачи в виде sql запроса в Oracle DB -

*дано* -

**Магазины:**
• ID
• Name

**Товары:**
• Id
• Name
• Price (стоимость за единицу)

**Продажи :**
• ID Магазина
• ID Товара
• Дата
• Количество единиц товара

*необходимо*:
Вывести информацию по 10 лучшим по выручке магазинам в разрезе месяца.

Такой вариант, наверное некорректен из-за использования Limit?

```
SELECT id.Магазины, Price*amount AS Выручка
    FROM ТОВАРЫ 
    INNER JOIN ПРОДАЖИ ON ТОВАРЫ.id.Товар=ПРОДАЖИ.id.Товар
    WHERE MONTH(date)=4
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: какая СУБД то у вас, и в чем проблема возникает?

Comment: Oracle.  нужна помощь в конкретном исполнении запроса

Comment: ну так промежуточных то итогов вы добились каких-то? как например просто вывести все магазины-товары-продажи одним запросом. а дальше например не знаете как использовать оконные функции для подсчета.

Comment: пока придумал только - JOIN таблиц ПРОДАЖИ и ТОВАРЫ, чтобы получить обобщенную таблицу с количеством и ценой, добавить колонку произведения количества на цену, группировать по ID магазина, упорядочить по убыванию, взять первые десять.  Но наверное это не самое оптимальное

Comment: так вы добавьте код в вопрос, напишите решает ли это вашу проблему, в чем вы видите недостатки. вам и подскажут конкретно по вопросу.

Comment: Да рано ещё про оконные функции. Сперва получите хотя бы для всех магазинов сумму месячной выручки. А потом уже будете выбирать 10 чемпионов.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше  с помощью DENSE_RANK (строкам с одинаковыми значениями выручки присвоятся одинаковые номера, причём по порядку, без пропусков(в отличие от RANK) и появится столбец "Лидер". Для получения итоговой таблицы предлагаю воспользоваться подзапросом с алиасом q:

```
    SELECT id.Магаз, Лидер \* итоговая таблица, куда можно добавить Выручку и что ещё потребуется*\
    FROM
    (
    SELECT id.Магаз, price*amount AS 
    Выручка
    DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY 
    price*amount DESC) AS Лидер 
    FROM ТОВАРЫ 
    INNER JOIN ПРОДАЖИ 
    ON ТОВАРЫ.id.Товар=ПРОДАЖИ.id.Товар 
    WHERE MONTH(date)=4
    GROUP BY 1)q 
    WHERE Лидер<=10;
```

Т.о.,DENSE_RANK() даст одно  и то же значение магазинам с одинаковой выручкой независимо от их количества - и все они будут учтены в столбце "Лидер".

Comment: Марина, верно что вывести именно 10 лидеров можно через функцию 9 FOLLOWING, -N (строк после текущей строки)?

Comment: Не думаю, неизвестно же, сколько магазинов будет с одинаковой выручкой